# Oracle DB, move row on update to another table

Tags: oracle, triggers, move

at the beginning was thinking it was something really easy to perform, but i'am stuck with the mutating error using trigger and I have no other idea on how to perform it
the main goal of this action is to avoid that the update line is performed twice ... so as soon as some fields are updated i need a process that move the row to another table (same fields in that table)

I have tried trigger with the AFTER update .. but  mutating error

I hope someone could help me

thank you in advance

Raph

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to debug code you can't see; why didn't you post a test case so that we'd see what you did and how Oracle responded?

---

Because, it *works* as expected - if I understood the question correctly. Here's how.

```
SQL> create table test (id number, name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create table test_2 (id number, name varchar2(20), datum date);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_ai_test
  2    after insert on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    insert into test_2 (id, name, datum)
  6      values (:new.id, :new.name, sysdate);
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into test (id, name) values (1, 'Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Littlefoot

SQL> select * From test_2;

        ID NAME                 DATUM
---------- -------------------- -------------------
         1 Littlefoot           07.01.2021 13:47:31

SQL>
```

---

I *presume* that your trigger selects from the table you created the trigger on (in my example, that would be `select ... from test`). You can't do that because of the mutating table error, but - you don't have to do it either as you can use `:new` and/or `:old` columns' values.

Answer (score 0):

exactly that ! mutating

I Have found a way to get it works :

create or replace TRIGGER TRIGGER1
After UPDATE OF AUTOMATICCOUNT ON SCAN4000

BEGIN
insert into SCAN4000_SAP (datamatrixcode, automaticcount) select scan4000.datamatrixcode, scan4000.automaticcount from  scan4000 where automaticcount is not null;
Delete from SCAN4000 where scan4000.automaticcount is not null;
END;

A colleague just told me that this could lead to DEADLOCKS,  what do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced  with same issue, better way it to avoid using triggers for such cases and change architecture of application.  May be doing this kind of stuff on application side.

Here are some important items to remember about triggers.

On insert triggers have no :OLD values.

On delete triggers have no :NEW values.

Triggers do not commit transactions. If a transaction is rolled back, the data changed by the trigger is also rolled back.

Commits, rollbacks and save points are not allowed in the trigger body. A commit/rollback affects the entire transaction, it is all or none.

Unhandled exceptions in the trigger will cause a rollback of the entire transaction, not just the trigger.

If more than one trigger is defined on an event, the order in which they fire is not defined. If the triggers must fire in order, you must create one trigger that executes all the actions in the required order.

A trigger can cause other events to execute triggers.
A trigger can not change a table that it has read from. This is the mutating table error issue.

Comment: As solution i can advice to use two  triggers instead of one. One for UPDATE AFTER , other for AFTER INSERT ( that deletes what  you need in first one ) .  I will check this out and return.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: two trigger solution is not working.